# Source for Impurity of an Uncovered Shabbos Table

Tags: sources-mekorot, shabbat

The Aruch Hashulchan OC (262:2) [writes](https://www.sefaria.org/Arukh_HaShulchan%2C_Orach_Chaim.262.2?lang=en&with=Translations&lang2=en) all the tables in one's home should be covered for Shabbos, and not doing so is a tremendous degradation to Shabbos:

כל השלחנות שבבית יהיו מוצעים במפות והמפות יהיו על השלחנות כל הלילה וכל היום עד מוצאי שבת וחושבין זה לבזיון גדול לשבת כשהשלחן מגולה.

In connection to such an idea, I heard story about someone possessed by an impure spirit (dibbuk) who saw the corner of a table which was partially uncovered on Shabbos and jumped at it with longing caresses - is there a source for such a story?